# Where are BLE characteristic and descriptor format specifications

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

Till some time back, I was able to access definitions of BLE services, characteristics and descriptor definitions on Bluetooth.com. There used to be a page with links to PDF and XML files for each standard service/characteristic/descriptor

It seems that these specifications are not available on the site any more. Or maybe I am looking in wrong places.

What is the current location of official BLE standard services and characteristics definitions? Are they publicly available?

Answer (score 0):

Found them.

They are now contained in a single pdf document named "GATT Specification Supplement" which is available from assigned numbers page.

Current link to assigned numbers page: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/

Comment: I was fed-up of searching for them for past week. Finally found it 10 min after asking question.